# Override name in variable

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function

```
public function saveImage(Request $request, $requestField, $path) {
        if ($request->hasFile($requestField)) {

            $image_path = public_path($this->{ $requestField });

            if (File::exists($image_path)) {
                File::delete($image_path);
            }

            $file = $request->file($requestField);
            $uploadname = $this->getUploadName($file);
            $pathFull = public_path($path);
            if (!File::exists($pathFull, 0775, true)) {
                File::makeDirectory($pathFull, 0775, true);
                }
            Image::make($file)->save($pathFull. $requestField. '-'. $uploadname);
            $this->{ $requestField } = $path. $requestField. '-'. $uploadname;

            return $file;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Next I call this function

```
$file = $article->saveImage($request, 'image_detail', '/storage/article/' .$article->id. '/');
```

The question now is, I have a `$requestField`, which now has the value `'image_detail'`

it should have this meaning everywhere, except for these lines

```
$pathFull. $requestField. '-'. $uploadname
$path. $requestField. '-'. $uploadname
```

I want the field `$requestField` to be converted to such a value `'image-detail'`, that is, to replace the underscore `'_'` with a dash `'-'`, is it possible to do this at all in this function only for separate lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **[Str::replace](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-str-replace)** method replaces a given string within the string:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str; 

$your_variable = 'image-detail';

$replaced = Str::replace('-', '_', $your_variable);

// image_detail
```